# Annotate a class member that doesn't exist (virtual property)

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, phpdoc

Is there a way to have an annotation for a class member that isn't declared explicitly? Like

```
class Foo
{
    /** @var string $bar */
    // public $bar; // <--- without this line

    ...other stuff...
}
```

Background: I use `__get` to provide virtual properties for my class and want these properties to appear in the phpstorm/idea autocomplete box.

Comment: `@property MyClass $bar` -- but do it in a PHPDoc for actual class: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#814-property

Comment: @LazyOne: ha, that's me the lazy one, not you! ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`@property`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html)* annotation on the class.

```
/**
 * @property string $bar
 */
class Foo {}
```

[image: Screenshot of PHPStorm's autocomplete box demonstrating.]

---

<sub>**or [`@property-read`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html) or [`@property-write`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-write.html) as appropriate.*</sub>